# Ohms volts amps calculations

Tags: electrical

If amps times ohms = volts.
In a household circuit, 120 volts, with 20 amps =6 ohms.
How does the wire gauge enter this equation?

Comment: You're applying Ohm's Law incorrectly.  It applies in certain circumstances.  Learn more electronics stuff. Sparkfun / Adafruit.

Comment: What home improvement problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Current ratings for wires are the **maximum** that the wire can carry safely. It’s the load that the wire is connected to that determines how much current actually flows.

Comment: Simple: your numbers indicate that your wires must not present more than 6 ohms to the outlet if they hope to provide the expected power. Luckily, household wiring is typically a tiny fraction of that amount. It also means that it takes 6 or fewer ohms to pop your breaker, which is why a short pops it instantly. If the wiring had 6 ohms, a short wouldn't pop the breaker, at least not for a long time, during which the overheated wires (energy has to go somewhere) could burn down the house.

Answer (score 2):

You're barking up the wrong tree with that logic, I'm afraid. Our system is based on constant voltage and variable current, so the voltage is 120V (or 230V in the rest of the world) and each appliance draws what it requires.  The amount it requires *had better be* less than the circuit ampacity/breaker trip.

You look at the equipment nameplate to determine the amps it actually requires.

If you had a heating element that was 6 ohms, it would draw 20 amps of power - that is true.  It would need a 125% derate per NEC 210.19, so the circuit would need to be provisioned for 25 amps.

NEC 240.4(D)(1-5) would then prohibit use of any wire smaller than 10 AWG, forcing you to follow 240.4(D)(6-7) and use at least 10 AWG wire.

If you are in larger stuff above 30A, then you consider the thermal limits of the wire insulation, route and terminations along with other adjustments in 310.15 and environs, then finally the ampacity chart at 310.15(B)(16).

Answer (score 1):

For basic household circuits, forget about Ohms.  Household appliances have stated amps or wattage along with voltage on their nameplates. If in wattage, divide wattage by voltage to get amps. Once you have the total amperage, you determine the wire size from the charts. Certain wires sizes have their maximum amps limited by required breaker sizes.

Ohms, resistance, would only come into play when dealing with extremely long circuits and voltage drops are a problem.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I was looking at an ohms law wheel when I saw that formula. 

Something very basic is eluding me. About wire gauge, circuit breaker size and appliance. I see 12 ga wire, 20 amp breaker. Does this mean all devices on that circuit using power at the same time can’t be more than about 15 amps (safety factor)? So if you know the amps of an appliance, say 30 you would need a 40 amp breaker and 8 gauge wire? Is too large a wire ever a problem?

Comment: @Mlew If you had 12 gauge wire and a 20 amp breaker and all the devices on that circuit kicked in at the same and the load exceeded 20 amps for a appropriate amount of time, the breaker would trip to protect the wire.  If you had a single device that required 30 amps, you'd need a 30 amp breaker and 10 gauge.  Too large a wire isn't a problem  if the proper breaker is used to provide what the device needs to run.

Comment: @Mlew  Larger size/gauge wire is sometimes even recommended.  The gauge listed for a certain amount of amps is the minimum.  Can usually go as large as you want if it fits/listed onto the device.  Cannot go below the minimum gauge on a circuit.

Comment: Okay, so the breaker needs to be the weakest link to protect the wire. What does the breaker size(20 amp) refer to? The max of 2,400 watts it can safely carry? 

So for a 240v circuit, why are stoves referred to as 30 amp for example. Because it draws 30 amps, or because it needs the wire size a 30 amp breaker protects?

Comment: @Mlew  for example, the stove calls for 30 amps because it has a number of heating elements for the stove top and oven.  The total amps for the elements is 30 so the manufacture states that 10 gauge wire, which is good for 30 amps ,and a 30 amp breaker  is needed for installation.  Yes, the breaker is the weakest link.. hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't, directly.  Wires do have resistance (ohms) that is a function of wire gauge, larger wire diameters having lower resistance than smaller wires.  Resistance is also a function of material, length, temperature, and frequency.  Since wires have resistance, there is a voltage drop along a wire that can be calculated from Ohm's law.  Since there is a voltage drop along a wire, there is power lost in the form of heating.  Power loss is proportional to the square of the current (amps).  More current results in more power loss and therefore more heating. Wires must be sized large enough that their temperature stays within a safe limit given the amount of current passing through.

In your house, voltage at 120V is provided, but the current drawn depends on the load being powered.  If you connect a 6 ohm resistive load, say a space heater, then the current would indeed by 20 amps, but load current varies depending on the device being powered, also not all loads are purely resistive